# MX Google Maps 2.8.1 compatibility

Tags: mx-google-map

I'm getting the following error when upgrading from MX Google Maps 1.4 -> 1.5.3 in EE 2.8.1

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Cp::set_variable() in /system/expressionengine/third_party/mx_google_map/mcp.mx_google_map.php on line 191

Anyone know if there's a fix for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made quick update - v. [1.5.3.140526](https://github.com/MaxLazar/mx-google-map-v1) wait for you

*update: first push was with mistake. download it now*